# Android apps not updating automatically

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have published an application and it went live after sometime. Now I have enabled automatic updates in the play store settings. I can see my app there and it's showing me update button. But why it is not automatically updated? Also i haven't got any notification about new update available?

Can anyone please tell how automatic updates work? App starts downloading update the time it is available or play store check updates after some interval?

Answer (score 2):

When an update to an application is published in the Play Store, updates start rolling out. Not all users will see the update immediately; I think the figure is a few hours for the update to be available throughout the country or world.

The Play Store app checks for updates periodically, I think a few times daily. You can configure toggles to:

1. Notify when updates are available
2. Automatically install updates
3. Notify when automatic updates have occurred

A user will only be alerted for an update if the application is installed from the Play Store. As a developer, you may have installed from adb, in which case the application will not update from the Play Store. You can always reinstall the Play Store version, which will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as answered above the updates don't happen right away. It could take up to 24 hrs for it to reach all users. The playstore generally updated when the device is idle and plugged in